# Timeseries Crossvalidation in R: using tsCV() with tslm()-Multiple model

Tags: r, function, cross-validation, forecasting

As a reaction on :[Timeseries Crossvalidation in R: using tsCV() with tslm()-Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255912/timeseries-crossvalidation-in-r-using-tscv-with-tslm-models/53672504#53672504)
I tried to use it with multiple predictor variables, i made a matrix of them, but it is not working.

```
    fcTslm <- function(y, h, xreg)
{
if(NROW(xreg) < length(y) + h)
stop("Not enough xreg data for forecasting")
X <- head(xreg, length(y))
fit <- tslm(y ~ X)
X <- subset(xreg, start=length(y)+1, end=length(y)+h)
forecast(fit, newdata=X)
}

> pred <- ts(cbind(rnorm(length(AirPassengers)),rnorm(length(AirPassengers))), start=start(AirPassengers),
+            frequency=frequency(AirPassengers))


> tsCV(AirPassengers, fcTslm, xreg=matrix(pred,ncol=2))
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1949  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1950  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1951  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1952  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1953  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1954  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1955  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1956  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1957  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1958  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1959  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1960  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

How can i make it working?

Answer (score 0):

```
function(y, h, xreg)
{
  X <- xreg[1:length(y),]
  if(NROW(xreg) < length(y) + h)
    stop("Not enough xreg data for forecasting")
  newX <- xreg[length(y)+(1:h),]
  fit <- tslm(y ~ X)
  forecast(fit, newdata=newX)
}

tsCV(AirPassengers, fcTSLM, xreg=matrix(pred,ncol=1))
```